# Copy transforms Constraint gives strange scaling and transforms?

Tags: transforms, constraints

I am using a **Copy transform Constraint** , But when I apply it this happens .[image]

I am trying to avoid , of course the mag stretching . **BUT** I have tried using Only, copy rot and Loc. That miserably fails because it moves the armature to the middle of nowhere, and rotates it awkwardly.

I am also trying to avoid Any scaling, **I have applied Scale**, to the armature and mesh, but that dos not work.

I have tried using "child of", It works but it doesn't **follow** it. It moves with it but lags behind and just doesn't cooperate with me.

Comment: Can you add an answer as to how you solved this otherwise it will be closed as it's not helping atm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the rig all along , The wrist bone was placed back at the elbow! , So i extruded a bone from the tip of the middle finger and used that , it had proper scaling and rotation.